# How to Implement an iOS Overlay in Shared Code Using the Media Plugin for Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to implement the overlay option for the media plugin in Xamarin, found here: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin

I understand how to use the feature in the iOS code, but am having trouble implementing it in the shared code.

Would really appreciate it if anyone knows what is wrong with my code, or if there is a working example of using the overlay feature in shared code.

I have setup an interface to handle the overlay for the iOS code, and have passed the function via a dependency service. It seems that the code block inside of func is skipping over when I set breakpoints and step into the function. The camera works but the overlay does not appear when using the camera.

IPhotoOverlay:

```
namespace Camera
{
public interface IPhotoOverlay 
{
   object GetImageOverlay();

    }
}
```

AppDelegate:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
    {
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
        LoadApplication(new App());

        Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Register<IPhotoOverlay, PhotoOverlay_iOS>();

        return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
    }
```

PhotoOverlay_iOS:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency (typeof (PhotoOverlay_iOS))]
namespace Camera.iOS
{
public class PhotoOverlay_iOS: IPhotoOverlay
{

    public PhotoOverlay_iOS ()
    {
    }

    public object GetImageOverlay()
    {

        Func<object> func = () =>
        {
            var imageView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromBundle("face-template.png"));
            imageView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;

            var screen = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
            imageView.Frame = screen;

            return imageView;
        };

        //Func<object> func = CreateOverlay;

        return func;
    }        

}
}
```

Shared Code:

```
var photo = await Plugin.Media.CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions()
            {
                OverlayViewProvider = DependencyService.Get<IPhotoOverlay>().GetImageOverlay,
                DefaultCamera = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.CameraDevice.Front
            });
```

Comment: Did the DependencyService work?

Comment: Yes the DependencyService seems to work. When I debug and set breakpoints it is being called and accessed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Solution:**

You can refer the following code .

> in Forms

```
async void OpenCameraAsync()
{         
  Func<object> func = () =>
  {
    var obj = DependencyService.Get<IPhotoOverlay>().GetImageOverlay();       
    return obj;
  };

  var photo = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions()
  {
     OverlayViewProvider =func,
     DefaultCamera = Plugin.Media.Abstractions.CameraDevice.Front,
  });
}
```

> in iOS project

```
public object GetImageOverlay()
{ 
  var imageView = new UIImageView(UIImage.FromBundle("yourimagename.png"));
  imageView.ContentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleAspectFit;

  var screen = UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds;
  imageView.Frame = screen;

  return imageView;               
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked for me. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: Is it possible `UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds` produces a problem? The overlay isn't quite centered on the bounds of our camera view rather it's slightly offset such that the mask is covering some of the phones UI and not just what's in the view of the picture being taken. Does this make sense?

Comment: Update: Thinking now this must be an offset issue relating to `Padding`. Will see what we can figure out...